# How to deny Group Policies from being applied to 1 PC

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, regedit

I know I can use gpmc.msc and deny my computer but there are policies that I can not modify so I want my PC to prevent processing Group Policies on my PC.

I know that drive mappings wont automagically appear but I can do that manually.

Is there any registry location that can be deleted or access denied by SYSTEM to prevent Group Policies?

We want to use this for a legitimate business use. It's not going to be used to hack a corporate PC

Comment: The "legitimate" way is to apply security filtering to the GPO, and/or put the computer into an OU where that policy isn't linked, or is blocked from applying.  So you should speak with your network admin and work with them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to permanently disable group policy updates on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/731397/is-it-possible-to-permanently-disable-group-policy-updates-on-windows-7), also see [Manually Override Power Settings in Windows 7 with a Group Policy in place](http://superuser.com/questions/475988/manually-override-power-settings-in-windows-7-with-a-group-policy-in-place?rq=1)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/593937/can-i-override-domain-group-policy-with-local-group-policy-as-a-local-admin

Comment: Yes, that SF link is in the accepted answer in the first question I linked to as a duplicate. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can move your computer to another OU where the policy is not linked . If the policy is on site level you must place your pc in a separate OU and block inheritance on that OU which I do not recommend . Or you need to check with your system administrator to apply the policies on groups and exclude you from the group which is highly unlikely to happen .